# Ionic add custom script with ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, gruntjs, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 via CLI.

While using ionic serve I want to add custom scripts "auth" which:

1. Prompts for username and password
2. creates cookie using api, and uses this cookie while calling each API.

**My `Gruntfile.js`**

I've created custom server task in grunt which:

1. Prompts the user for login
2. Creates cookies and applies this cookie with each request.
3. Is able to manage run with ionic from `package.json`.

```js
grunt.registerTask('server', ['checkAuthToken', 'applyAuthToken', 'configureRewriteRules', 'configureProxies']);

"scripts": { "auth": "grunt server", }
```

Now I am wondering how to import this auth task before ionic serve so that my proxy and authentication works.

**Scripts in my `package.json`**

I tried with below npm-script in my `package.json`. It prompts for username, password, and creates cookies, however my proxy doesn't work because my grunt task is run after ionic watch and before ionic build.

```json
...
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve && grunt server",
"ionic:serve": "grunt server && ionic-app-scripts serve"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you have ionic cli then you use `ionic:build:before` in your scripts section of package.json.

Example: package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "ionic:build:before": "grunt server"
  }
```